# Use same method to add 1 to a casted string that can be either float or int

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Think this is a generic vs type specific problem.
I would like to add a unit to a string casted argument that can be an `int` or a `float`.
I tried the following, but there is problem at the time of the cast because the type is not known at compile time.

```
namespace ConsoleApp17
{
    class Program
    {
        static int myInt = 1;
        static float myFloat = 2f;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myFloatStr = "1.3";
            string myIntStr = "2";
            Add<float>(myFloatStr, SetNewFloatValue);
            Add<int>(myIntStr, SetNewIntValue);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static void Add<T>(string str, Action<T> action)
        {
            T valueToSet = (T)Math.Round(double.Parse(str) + 1, 0 , MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //problem here, cannot convert double to T
            action(valueToSet);
        }

        private static void SetNewFloatValue(float floatArg) {
            myFloat += floatArg;
        }

        private static void SetNewIntValue(int intArg)
        {
            myInt += intArg;
        }

    }
```

}

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q5rEY3) in case its helpful.
Is method overload for each of the arguments the only solution for this, or is there a more elegant solution so that the same funtionality can be dealt with in the one same method for both types `float` and `int`?

Meaning that:

```
Add<float>(myFloatStr, SetNewFloatValue);
Add<int>(myIntStr, SetNewIntValue);
```

could be done with the one same method.

Comment: This doesn't work for the reason you describe, at least until recently. A possible workarounds is the use of the `dynamic` type. C# 10 does have a feature that's exactly for this purpose, I haven't tried that yet, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using older versions than .Net 6, you can use `Convert.ChangeType` for your case.

```
T valueToSet = (T)Convert.ChangeType(Math.Round(double.Parse(str) + 1, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 2):

"Generic Math" is what you want. This feature is a preview feature in .NET 6.0/C#10. It is described in detail [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/).

This allows method declarations such as this one:

```cs
public static TResult Sum<T, TResult>(IEnumerable<T> values)
    where T : INumber<T>
    where TResult : INumber<TResult>
{
    TResult result = TResult.Zero;

    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        result += TResult.Create(value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The `INumber` interface is the magic of this concept. It is implemented on most numeric types now.

Previously, you had to implement that manually (by specifying your own `INumber` interface, with Add(), Subtract() etc. methods) or use the `dynamic` type to evaluate the correct types at runtime. The former was a lot of boilerplate to write for this, the later is slow.